# scala scalikejdbcでのupdateについて

Tags: scala, playframework, scalikejdbc

scalaで開発をしております。
scalikejdbcで自動で作成されたコードでCRUDの処理をしたいと思いましたが
Update文だけできません。

```
object hoge extends SQLSyntaxSupport[hoge] {
  def save(entity: hoge)(implicit session: DBSession = autoSession): hoge = {
    withSQL {
      update(hoge).set(
        column.id -> entity.id,
        column.test-> entity.test
      ).where.eq(column.id, entity.id)
    }.update.apply()
    entity
  }
}
```

MVCでのcontrollerの部分の処理をお願いします。
この処理を教えてください。
環境は、

- Mac OS X
- scala + play framework

です。

Comment: 「Update文だけできません」について、何かエラーメッセージなどが表示されるのでしたら、それを追記して下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: heliac2001 書き方がわからないので書き方まで教えてもらえると幸いです。

Comment: @heliac2001 さんへ。編集タイミンが被ったのか、自分の s/scalike/scalikejdbc の編集が元に戻されてしまったのですが・・・(scalikejdbcが正式名称であり、scalikeは間違い)

Comment: @KenjiYoshida すみません Yoshida さん、先程修正しました。

Comment: この生成されたscalikejdbcのコード自体は動く(というかコンパイルは通る)けど、これを利用する側のController側のコードの書き方がわからない、という意味でしょうか？

Comment: そうですねscalikejdbcのコード自体は動きます
Controllerのコードの書き方がわからないと言う意味です
言葉足らずで申し訳ありません。

Comment: @mizutama いえ、こちらこそ勘違いをしてしまい申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 2):

もう少し具体的に聞いてもらわないと、そもそもどこがわかってないのかを回答者が把握するのが難しいので、まずは、scalikejdbc本体にplayと組み合わせたサンプルがあるので、以下のあたりのコードや

モデル側のコード
- https://github.com/scalikejdbc/hello-scalikejdbc/blob/d9be942770a1e815e1d6626c79b471fa4a7036ce/app/models/Programmer.scala

それを使っているplayのコントローラー側のコード
- https://github.com/scalikejdbc/hello-scalikejdbc/blob/d9be942770a1e815e1d6626c79b471fa4a7036ce/app/controllers/Programmers.scala

playの公式のドキュメントを読んで勉強してもらってから、もう少し具体的に質問し直してもらう、もしくは質問内容をより具体的なものに変えてもらうのがいいかと思います。

または、勉強用に全部を公開できるコードなら、途中でもいいので、とにかくコード全体を公開して見てもらう、などでしょうか

Comment: サンプル見たらすぐに実装できました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @mizutama 本回答で解決できた場合には回答の承認をよろしくお願いします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers